# Gmail is not delivering email with a link

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Am using phpmailer to send email from my Gmail account.
Gmail is not delivering emails if I have a link in message body. Here is my email

Dear Zeeshan,

Thank you again for calling Test. We improve our service based on your feedback. Will you please rate your experience to let us know how we did? Click on the link below!

[Click Here to Share Your Review](http://rsasatisfaction.com/home/feedback/57/1/Zeeshan/shah.zeshan@gmail.com)

**If I remove the link, email works fine. What is issue with this link?
Here is what gmail send me back**

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

      shah.zeshan@gmail.com

 Technical details of permanent failure:
 Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

 ----- Original message -----

 X-Received: by 10.202.67.133 with SMTP id q127mr3207265oia.116.1455592533646;
         Mon, 15 Feb 2016 19:15:33 -0800 (PST)
 Return-Path: <lockandtowservice@gmail.com>
 Received: from rsasatisfaction.com (rs43.whbdns.com. [209.105.241.194])
         by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id pp10sm17110856obc.16.2016.02.15.19.15.32
         for <shah.zeshan@gmail.com>
         (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
         Mon, 15 Feb 2016 19:15:32 -0800 (PST)
 Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 03:15:31 +0000
 Return-Path: lockandtowservice@gmail.com
 To: shah.zeshan@gmail.com
 From: Test <lockandtowservice@gmail.com>
 Subject: Share Your Review For Test
 Message-ID: <5b7609c465e4ebe2ef057cc7f0db582f@rsasatisfaction.com>
 X-Priority: 3
 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
         boundary="b1_5b7609c465e4ebe2ef057cc7f0db582f"

 <p>
 Dear Zeeshan,
 </p>
 <p>
Thank you again for calling Test. We improve our
 service based on your feedback. Will you please
 rate your experience to let us know how we did?
 Click on the link below!
</p>
 <p>
 <a
 href="http://rsasatisfaction.com/home/feedback/57/1/Zeeshan/shah.zeshan@gmail.com">Click
 Here to Share Your Review</a>
 </p>

 <p>

 Thank you again. If we can be of more service,
 please let us know.
</p>
 <p>
 Warm regards,<br>
 Test<br>
 </p>
```

Comment: Not delivering? Or delivering to the Spam folder? Also, what does `$mail->send()` return, and is there anything in `$mail->ErrorInfo`?

Comment: You should URL-encode the `@` in the URL.

Comment: Hard to tell with that little info. Maybe it's just precaution because the domain is brand new (= no reputation) + it contains personal data and perhaps it is also linked to other domains with low reputation (xy.ninja)...?

Comment: @Amadan by not delivering I mean being rejected from google. Here is what I get

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

      shah.zeshan@gmail.com

 Technical details of permanent failure:
 Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

 ----- Original message -----
.........

Comment: @lukeA I have added more details in question. will this help

Comment: The "issue with this link", as well as your next steps, have been spelled out for you by the error message.

Comment: @ITGuru What if you just include http://rsasatisfaction.com/ in the link, no personal data?

Comment: @lukeA there is no other way, this is a review site with no dashboard. This link is only way user can land to exact page

Comment: Well, you want to find the reason for getting blocked. This is trial and error. Maybe it's because of the email address (in addition to the domain having no reputation and having only one link and...)

Comment: @lukeA I tried removing email from URL and same issue, I think domain repo can not be the case or new  sites can not work with google email ever :)

Comment: That alone will not be enough, but a modern spamfilter - especially with a training set like the one Gmail has - will probably judge an uncountable number of combinations of thousands of features - like having a gmail-fromaddress, promoting just one link, which leads to a brand new domain and has personal identifieable information in it etc.